# Reading two matrices from two files and outputting a matrix of the two multiplied

Tags: java, matrix

I have to write a program that reads two input files that have text matrices, multiply those matrices, and output the final matrix. The size of the matrix (ie: 4x3, 2x3) must be included in the first line of the output file.

File1:

4x2:

1   2

3   4

5   6

7   8

File2:

2x3

1   2   3

4   5   6

Output:

4x3

9   12  15

19  26  33

29  40  51

39  54  69

```
package Programs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
public static void multiply(File input_file1, File input_file2, File      output_file) {
    try {
        Scanner firstScan = new Scanner(input_file1);
        Scanner secondScan = new Scanner(input_file2);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output_file);

        int[][] matrixOne = new int[][] {};
        int[][] matrixTwo = new int[][] {};

        firstScan.nextLine();
        secondScan.nextLine();
        while (firstScan.hasNext()) {
            for (int row = 0; row < input_file1.length(); row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < input_file1.length(); col++) {
                    matrixOne[row][col] = firstScan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        while (secondScan.hasNext()) {
            for (int row = 0; row < input_file2.length(); row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < input_file2.length(); col++) {
                    matrixTwo[row][col] = secondScan.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        int [][] result = new int[][] {};
        writer.println(result);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return;
    }
}
}
```

I realize the "result" matrix is not the actual correct answer. Am I reading and setting the files correctly to matrices? And how do I go about multiplying them?

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[][] calMatrix(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

    int c[][] = new int[a.length][b[0].length];

    int x, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
            int temp = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < b.length; x++) {
                temp += a[i][x] * b[x][j];

            }
            c[i][j] = temp;

        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

This is the multiple algorithm.

just call it

there has an completely answer.
[this answer is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388444/764869)

Comment: I tried running it in a main and got an output of "[[I@15db9742", any idea why?

Comment: It tells how to print an array  private static void displayMatrix( int[][] matrix ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i ) {
         for( int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j ) {
            System.out.printf( "%2d ", matrix[i][j] );
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

   }